# Which 3D printing technology will Archinaut vessel use?

Tags: reduced-gravity-manufacturing

The 3D printing company Made in Space works on a device to introduce 3D printing in space referenced as [Archinaut](http://www.projectarchinaut.com/). Is it known which technology/material will be used?

Comment: The archinaut satellite system isn't really a 3d printer, it's more of a manufacture/assembly robot